# .htaccess null variable giving 403 forbidden error

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am using .htacces file like this:

```
RewriteRule ^folder/(.*).html$ file.php?mode=$1 [L,NC]
```

There are no problem like this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/folder/qwerty.html
```

But it is giving 403 forbidden error like this URL:

```
http://www.example.com/folder/.html
```

(P.s: This issue not a big problem. Only i want to learn how can i fix this issue and i need to fix it for security reasons.)

(P.s2: i tried to change file.php for "if mode == null" but still 403 error.)

Thanks...

Comment: `if (empty($_GET'mode'])) { // mode not set }` in `file.php`?

Comment: I think all .ht* files are forbidden by default because .htaccess files are like that.

Comment: @mkjasinski look at p.s2. Page not executing. Error coming before file execution.

Comment: i think solve must like this:(.*) pattern saying all characters. But if i can say all characters and null values in pattern; this will solve this issue. But how?

Answer (score 1):

The default configuration for Apache contains a section:

```
#
# The following lines prevent .htaccess and .htpasswd files from being
# viewed by Web clients.
#
<Files ~ "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy all
</Files>
```

Your URL containing "/.html" matches this, as the file part of the path with ".ht", and so it denies access before it reaches your rewrite rules.

You would have to override this; either by making the section above more specific and only matching .htaccess and .htpasswd to deny them, or by overriding the match to re-allow .html, with something like:

```
<Files ~ "^\.html">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

... within your .htaccess file.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But still 403 error. This is logical answer but didn't work for me.